# Debugging memory leaks

Tags: programming, bugs, memory, debugging

I've written my incredibly complex, incredibly elegant analysis function, that works great on small test data. But when I run it on my real (bigger) data set it keeps running out of memory. It turns out that the analysis function does not free memory, but I can't imagine why. It takes a large number of points, but returns only several scalar values.

[image: memory usage after time]

Every time I run this it takes up about 500 MB of memory. ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4qHS.png) is another example).

**What is the best way to debug memory problems?**

I've read the [memory management](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MemoryManagement.html) tutorial, turned off [caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638702/mathematica-running-out-of-memory) and verified I have no [lingering variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867892/reducing-memory-usage-in-an-extended-mathematica-session) in my contexts and of course I have set `$HistoryLength` to zero.

Also running `` Reverse@Sort[{ByteCount[Symbol[#]], #} & /@ Names["`*"]] `` show no huge memory symbols. Just the data:

```
{{191816648, "alldata"}, {28184, "before"}, {28184, "after"},
 {24096, "compiledSelectBin"}, {15344, "AppendLeftRight"}, {8840, "compiledSelectBinFunc"}...}
```

**EDIT**
One can use this code to track memory consumption:

```
DynamicModule[{pm = {}},
 Dynamic@Refresh[pm = Append[pm, MemoryInUse[]]; 
   If[Length[pm] > 120, pm = Drop[pm, 1]]; 
   ListPlot[pm/1024/1024, AxesLabel -> {"Time [s]", "Memory [MB]"}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, All}], UpdateInterval -> 1, 
   TrackedSymbols :> {}]]
```

I *think* I finally have a minimum example. [Here it is](http://lbf.ijs.si/ajasja/mails/Mathematica/Leak/Leak.zip). Unzip to a folder and evaluate the two cells in LeakP.nb. If you evaluate the second cell multiple times you can watch the memory consumption grow. **Could somebody (on win7 64 bit mma 8) confirm this?**

**EDIT 1**

I *really hope* I have nailed it down. Here is a self contained example:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 100000, 2}];
data = Developer`ToPackedArray[#] & /@ data;
data = Flatten[data, 1];
Dimensions[data]
HistogramList[data, 30, Automatic];
ClearAll[data]; ClearSystemCache[];
```

**EDIT 2**

This is fixed in *Mathematica* 9.0.0.

Comment: the question you ask is impossible to answer in any non speculative way without seeing the code. Having said that and assuming for a second that you did follow the typical suggestions have you tried to explicitly set all variables in your `Module`/`Block` to Null right after they are not used any longer?

Comment: @rubenko No, not yet. Also, I'm not asking where is my problem, I'm asking how to start tracking it down. (Aha, the question in the image is rhetorical:)  This is a largish piece of code (about 600 lines) and I'm at a loss where to begin...

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but in a comparable situation I found that using Share[] in the routine reduced the memory footprint considerably. See for example [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2735/mathematica-rule-substitution-memory)

Comment: @Ajasja, you need to simplify your code and monitor memory during while doing that.

Comment: @ruebenko Do you mean just printing `MemoryInUse[]` in various places?

Comment: @Ajasja, yes, and `MaxMemoryUsed[]`. Perhaps something like `mem := {MemoryInUse[]/1024.^2, MaxMemoryUsed[]/1024.^2}`

Comment: @rubenko Oh, I just remembered, I'm passing large arrays to compiled functions (With `CompilationTarget -> C`). Are there any known memory leaks when doing that?

Comment: @Ajasja, not that I know about.

Comment: Perhaps it's time to try constructing a minimal working example and share it.  If the mistake is indeed in your code (and it's not a bug in some Mathematica function you're using), it would be very worthwhile to learn about it, for all of us.  (If you post a working example: please note that some of us only have 2 GB of memory, so scale it down a bit :)

Comment: Note that `ByteCount[sym]` will only show the memory used by the `OwnValues` for the symbol. I introduced the `symbolMemoryUsage` function in my answer specifically to address other global properties as well.

Comment: @Ajasja, with the edit: you could try the following: add the dummy line: `thisDoesNothing;` before and after the call to `compiledSelectBin` and see if the mem consumption goes down.

Comment: @rubenko No change in memory consumption.

Comment: Did you make progress on this since your last edit?

Comment: I think @acl gave a very sound suggestion: try to refactor your code so that it is built from really small functions and use as little state as possible. It should then be much easier to locate the place where leak is happening.

Comment: @Szabolcs Are you on win7? I uploaded an example of the leak...

Comment: @Ajasja Nope, WinXP and 32 bit, but I'll try.

Comment: @Szabolcs It seems that just running `steps = Import["steps.mx"];
ClearAll[steps]` is enough. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @Ajasja You removed the edit just before I could try it, is it not the cause of the problem after all?

Comment: @Szabolcs No, to my shame I forgot to add `$HistoryLength = 0;` to the sample (I have it set in my package files...)

Comment: @Ajasja Don't worry, I just managed to do the same myself :-)

Comment: @ruebenko I managed to put together a minimal example that leaks memory. Do you perhaps know why?

Comment: @Ajasja, I don't have access to windows right now. You assume that the leak is can be seen with the ` QucikDensityHistogram`. If so, try to comment out your ListContourPlot and see if it then still leaks. If it does comment out the previous line until you find the line that causes the leak. If you could reduce that to a notebook, that were good.

Comment: @ruebenko I narrowed it down to `HistogramList`. Please see edit.

Comment: I can confirm the leak in 32-bit WinXP.

Comment: @Ajasja, I forwarded this to a developer but have not heard back yet.

Comment: @rubenko Do you think I need to file a bug report, or will it be fixed in the next version?

Comment: @Ajasja, thanks for tracking it down. The respective developers are looking and this will hopefully be resolved soon in the development version. So no need for a bug report.

Comment: @Ajasja have you seen [this](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/952/52)?

Comment: I recently found a memory leak associated with using two native functions, Area and Triangle, together.  I found it by eliminating code from the function until the error no longer occurred, eventually isolating it to the one offending line, `Area[Triangle[#]]&/@coordinates` on a coordinates list.  A similar dissection of your function until you find the offending line may work.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### Preamble

It is hard to say what exactly is causing this without seeing the code, but, assuming that there are no memory leaks in the built-in functions you are using, I am only aware of a very few possible causes for memory leaks in Mathematica. Since almost anything is immutable, the leaks must be associated with some symbols for which definitions are accumulated but not cleared.

I will show here one rather obscure case of leaking of local `Module` variables, which happens when the variable is referenced by some object / symbol, external w.r.t. its scope. In such cases, such variables are not garbage-collected even after the symbols referencing them get `Remove`-d, in case if they get assigned `DownValues`, `SubValues` or `UpValues` (`OwnValues` are ok).

#### One subtle case with a memory leak

```
MemoryInUse[]
```

> ```
>  17350016
> ```

```
$HistoryLength = 0;

Module[{g},
  Module[{f},
    g[x_] := f[x];
    Do[f[i] = Range[i], {i, 5000}];
  ];
  g[1]]
```

> ```
>  {1}
> ```

```
MemoryInUse[]
```

> ```
>  72351376
> ```

One way to ensure that this does not happen is to insert `Clear[f]` at the end of the outer `Module`, storing the result in a separate variable and returning it afterwards. There are more advanced ways to prevent such things as well. I may elaborate on those at some later time.

#### Memory leaks associated with UI-building

One common cause of memory leaks which is often ovelooked is when some local symbols make it into UI elements. The problem is that UI elements are Mathematica expressions, which do reference those symbols, and therefore, they are not garbage-collected.

Here is an example I borrowed from [this thread](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/)

```
memModule[] := 
  Module[{data, memBefore, mu}, 
     mu := Grid[{{"Memory in use: ", MemoryInUse[]/(2^30.), "GB"}}]; 
     memBefore = mu; 
     data = RandomReal[1, {300000, 20}]; 
     DynamicModule[{d1}, 
        d1 := data[[1]]; 
        Panel[Grid[{{memBefore}, {mu}}]] 
       , UnsavedVariables -> {dl} 
    ] 
 ];
```

Now, every time when it gets executed, more memory is being leaked:

```
memModule[] 
memModule[] 
memModule[]
```

Please see my answer in the linked thread for one way out, in this particular case. Generally, this is something to watch out for.

#### Monitoring symbols

So, one good place to start is to call

```
Names["Global`*"]
```

> ```
>  {"f", "f$", "f$119", "g", "i", "x", "x$"}
> ```

or whatever main context you are using (or other contexts, if you create symbols there), and watch for some symbols with high memory usage. In this particular case, the culprit it `f$119`.

Here are some utility functions which may help with monitoring symbols:

```
Clear[$globalProperties];
$globalProperties =
    {OwnValues, DownValues, SubValues, UpValues, NValues, 
     FormatValues, Options, DefaultValues, Attributes, Messages};

ClearAll[getDefinitions];
SetAttributes[getDefinitions, HoldAllComplete];
getDefinitions[s_Symbol] :=
    Flatten@Through[
        Map[
           Function[
              prop, 
              (* Unevaluated needed here just for Options, which is not holding *)
              Function[sym, prop[Unevaluated @ sym], HoldAll]
           ],
           $globalProperties
        ][Unevaluated[s]]
      ];

ClearAll[symbolMemoryUsage];
symbolMemoryUsage[sname_String] :=
   ToExpression[sname, InputForm, 
      Function[s, ByteCount[getDefinitions[s]], HoldAllComplete]
   ];

ClearAll[heavySymbols];
heavySymbols[context_, sizeLim_: 10^6] :=
   Pick[#, UnitStep[# - sizeLim] &@Map[symbolMemoryUsage, #], 1] &@
        Names[context <> "*"];
```

For example, calling

```
heavySymbols["Global`"]
```

returns

> ```
>  {f$119}
> ```

Comment: +1 Thank you for the example. Now I understand the comment you made [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867892/reducing-memory-usage-in-an-extended-mathematica-session). Unfortunately, there appear to be no heavy symbols. `heavySymbols[""]`, returns `{"alldata", "GeoProjectionData"}` which is that data I loaded at the beginning and an always present built-in.

Comment: @Ajasja Well, then I am at a loss. Do you create symbols in other contexts? Or, do you return any expression involving local variables, or embed it into UI, for example? UI-s are another cause of memory leaks, see e.g. my answer in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/9339496428c3ce02)

Comment: @Ajasja I also had a situation with the kernel eating up gigabytes of memory, linearly increasing in time even though I never kept more than 1GB of data in symbols. I also had checked and no symbols had anywhere near the memory consumed. in the end I rewrote my program in a completely different way and now it doesn't eat memory. have no clue what it was.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I don't create symbols in any other context. What I'm doing a lot is assigning to the same Module variable multiple times. For example `data=rawdata; data=GetDiffrences[data]; data=Mean[data]... Return[data]` But I belive this shuld be safe. I'm putting memory print statements all over my code as we speak...

Comment: @acl Brr... that would be a worst case scenario! I spent two weeks on this code and now I can't get a single result...

Comment: @Ajasja There does seem to be an unstoppable (inaccessible) memory sink somewhere deep in Mathematica. I've run into it with my own application. The only reliable way around it seems to be re-architecture (cf acl above). In my case, the sink was somewhere under a huge inner product. Leonid eliminated that for me, i.e. http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Jan/msg00829.html.

Comment: @Vince Hi Vince, nice to see that you are here! (I mean, I did not realize before that you are you :)).

Comment: @Leonid Thanks Leonid. It's a sporadic presence, and usually rushed. While I'm off-topic, let me say how impressed I am with what has been created here on SE for MMA. A lot of impressive dedication and substantial contribution.

Comment: @Vince Thanks Vince! Lots of great folks accumulated here, from Stack Overflow, Mathgroup, WRI, and elsewhere. I think what makes this place stand out and compare favorably to, say, Mathgroup (with all due respect for the latter), is the level of collaboration (by which I also mean a healthy competition, which is often very beneficial for everybody), and the sense of community as a whole, rather than a set of isolated experts. Hope to see a lot of your answers appearing here!

Comment: @Ajasja Buried in the link I included above, you can see that my problematic memory profile resembles yours. Not sure if all memory profiles of MMA functions look this way (if not flat).  ![memory profile](http://tinyurl.com/yfgwp26). (How to display an image in a Comment?)

Comment: @Vince: working set is probably not a reliable indicator of actual memory usage. A program that repeatedly allocates and frees memory can result in a highly inflated working set metric, because in a system under a light memory load, the memory manager will just put freed pages on the standby list without actually freeing them in case they're allocated again soon afterward. Just because the working set or virtual size is large, it doesn't necessarily mean that the process is using all that memory.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I was trying to find the total RAM footprint of jobs which I was running remotely on other users' Windows XP desktops (to maintain their performance). perfmon's "Process > Working Set" seemed to approximate that footprint best. Also, supposedly, MMA tries very hard to recycle memory it has already taken from the system. I didn't see that in my memory profiles. By your clarification, it seems that recycling would keep the Working Set down, since it would eliminate many system memory allocations. Again, that was not apparent in the profiles. But maybe I'm not following.

Comment: @Vince: in that case, working set seems like a reasonable metric, considering that a pessimistic estimate is probably better for this application. It's not very useful for assessing possible memory leaks though. Personally I'd tend not to put much faith in claims like "*Mathematica* tries to..." unless you know what they really mean in practice. *Mathematica* doesn't have a great deal of control over the OS's memory management policies, which vary by system load, OS version, and many other unpredictable factors.

Comment: @OleksandrR. The bit about "recycling" was something I got from WRI's tech support. Voodoo to me.

Comment: @Vince I got the memory profile from `pm = {}
Dynamic@Refresh[pm = Append[pm, MemoryInUse[]]; 
  ListPlot[pm/1024/1024, AxesLabel -> {"Time [s]", "Memory [MB]"}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, All}], UpdateInterval -> 1, TrackedSymbols :> {}]` so it should be reliable.

Comment: @Ajasja No doubt it's at least a reliable relative measure. I needed a system-level metric. That is, how well math.exe would play with others in the system process list. Working Set was as close as I could get. (MemoryInUse[] always under-reported.) I'll mention again that, though the scale is different, our memory profiles have very similar shapes. I find that intriguing. But perhaps common, as I also obliquely commented above somewhere.

Comment: @Vince I think such a shape could be common. Some memory is allocated (that will not get released) and then some further processing allocates even more memory, but then frees it. BTW, you can't embed images in comments, you can only link to them (to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: @Ajasja The sticking point is in your first parenthetical remark. My inner products, though large, were very simple operations and did not leave residual temporaries (at the user level). Yet the size of the final product was much smaller than indicated in the memory profile. Though please take these observations carefully; it's been a long time since I've run this diagnostic.

Comment: When I run `heavySymbols["Global\`", 10^6]` after some code some functions from my code start evaluating. Could some HoldAll be missing? Or any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Also how does this work with different Wolfram Kernels? I can see, in Gnome-Monitor, a high memory usage (3.2GB) in 6 different kernels (I called 6 kernels in a ParallelMap so that part makes sense). Apparently these are still alive after the parallel computation has already finished. In addition I see the main Kernel which has an memory usage  that is close to the value returned by MemoryInUse[] (~1GB). So do these debugging tools only show the usage in the main kernel. It seems my problem isn't there.

Comment: Ah profiling memory usage in subkernels is simple you just need to use `ParallelEvaluate` so in this case for example `ParallelEvaluate[heavySymbols["Global\`", 10^6]]`

Comment: @Kvothe There was indeed an evaluation leak coming from `Options` not holding its argument - which would show up for symbols with  `OwnValues`, such as e.g. `a := Print["***"]` - then calling `getDefinitions` on `a` would lead to printing. I have made and edit that should fix it, check it out. Regarding parallel, it looks like you already found an answer.

Comment: Thanks, indeed your update fixed the evaluation leak.

Comment: @Kvothe Excellent. Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 13):

This is a memory leak in `HistogramList`:

You can reclaim the memory by evaluating

```
Remove["*`*modelData$*"]
```

Comment: Using the previous answer with heavySymbols["*`"] allows to find this. Great case study !

Comment: Isn't ``Remove["System`HistogramListDump`modelData$*"]`` safer?