# Obtaining better quality in ListPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, export

I have a data file which can be downloaded from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?wb5v661tsp0csi0).

In order to plot this, I use the following Mathematica code

```
SetDirectory[" ... "];
data = Import["pss_data.dat", "Table"];
S0 = ListPlot[data, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"x", OverDot["x"]}, RotateLabel -> False, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[0.001]}, 
PlotRange -> {{-10.1, 11}, {-45, 45}}, ImageSize -> 550]
Export["pss_plot.eps", S0, "EPS"];
```

However, the quality of the plot is not satisfactory. Let me be more specific. I realized, that the element which causes the problem is indeed the `PointSize` option. Here is a magnification of the .eps output created using Mathematica

[image]

OK, this is a decent plot, but take a look at this one created using gnuplot

[image]

Now, the problem it is far from obvious. The dots which represent the points are way too big in the Mathematica plot. I tried to reduce the `PointSize` of them, but it seems that it cannot be smaller 0.001. You may insert 0.0001 but these is no effect. I even tried to `Rasterize` the plot before export it to .eps but again I could not achieve the desired quality.

So, my question: Is it possible to achieve the same plot using Mathematica? Well, it should be. In fact, the question can be rephrased as: How could we shrink more the `PointSize` in `ListPlot`?

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Following Jens's method the output .eps file is the following:

[image]

Obviously, almost the entire right part of the plot is missing. Only if I set `Magnification -> 1` I can obtain all the plot. But then, zooming in you can see that the dots are still big enough as in my initial output. So, back to square one!

Comment: How about changing `PlotStyle -> Directive[Gray, PointSize[0.001], Opacity[0.5]]` ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks The same output as before. Only now the dots are with gray color. Their size has not been reduced.

Comment: Βαγγέλη, I have had a go and I can export the whole plot with `ImageSize->1000` onto eps. Also, there is a potentially [related question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9189/) with adaptive point size for dense plots

Comment: @gpap How did you manage to obtain the entire plot using `ImageSize->1000`? Anyway, are dots smaller now? If you zoom inside the plot does it look like the gnuplot output?

Comment: Yes, the dots seem fine in [my export](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6886148/pss_plot1.eps). But if they don't I think the question I linked to will definitely be of help

Comment: @gpap In your export about half of the plot is missing form the output .pes file! Don't you think that this is a problem?!

Comment: Huh?!? Osx automatically converts it to pdf and looks perfect. It's never been so different to the respective eps. I'll probably need to check against including it in a latex document-sincere apologies

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Strictly speaking what you observe is a bug in handling of the `Point` `Graphics` primitive by `Export`.

One workaround is to export to SVG format, edit it and then save as EPS. Here is a way to go (some numbers may be version-specific, I use *Mathematica* 9.0.1):

```
Export["test.svg",
  StringReplace[ExportString[S0, "SVG"], 
    "rx='0.5' ry='0.5'" -> "rx='0.2' ry='0.2'"], "String"]
```

The exported SVG file can be opened by Inkscape 0.48.3.1 and then saved to EPS or PDF format. Here is how exported PDF file looks in Adobe Acrobat 11:

[image: screenshot]

You can tune the size `0.2` of the circles for your taste.

---

**EDIT**

In a comment @cormullion suggets more direct approach which does not  require an intermediate program:

```
Export["test.eps",
  StringReplace[ExportString[S0, "EPS"], {"\t" -> " ", " 1 w" -> " 0.3 w"}], "String"]
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Here is another, much more direct approach:

```
S0 = Graphics[{Disk[#, .01] & /@ data}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"x", OverDot["x"]}, RotateLabel -> False, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"],
    PlotRange -> {{-10.1, 11}, {-45, 45}}, ImageSize -> 550, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio];
Export["pss_plot.eps", S0];
```

Here is how exported EPS file looks opened in Acrobat 11:

[image: screenshot 2]

---

**EDIT 3**

Here is a way to export EPS file with rasterized plot (about 900 kb in size):

```
S0 = Graphics[{Disk[#, Offset[.3]] & /@ data}, Axes -> False, 
   Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", OverDot["x"]}, 
   RotateLabel -> False, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"],
    PlotRange -> {{-10.1, 11}, {-45, 45}}, ImageSize -> 550, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio];

Export["pss_plot.eps", 
  Rasterize[Style[S0, Antialiasing -> False], "Image", 
   ImageResolution -> 1000]];
```

If you need higher resolution you can increase the `ImageResolution`. If you want to add a preview to the EPS file, use the `"PreviewFormat"` option:

```
Export["pss_plot.eps", 
  Rasterize[Style[S0, Antialiasing -> False], "Image", 
   ImageResolution -> 1000], "PreviewFormat" -> "TIFF"];
```

Note that rasterization with high resolution requires a lot of memory and *Mathematica* cannot use more than approximately 1.2 Gb of memory under 32 bit systems. The memory requirements can be reduced by incremental rendering (see the "EDIT 4" section below).

Here is how exported plot looks in Adobe Acrobat (I switched off downsampling for bitmap images in Acrobat's [EPS → PDF conversion settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4f8b.png)):

[image: screenshot 3]

---

**EDIT 4**

For completeness, here I present an incremental rendering technique which allows substantially reduce the memory requirements when rendering *Mathematica*'s graphics with high resolution. It works both for `Graphics` and `Graphics3D`. Note that for the current task I convert the image to grayscale for saving memory, generally it is not necessary.

One can also note the loose of `FrameLabel` - it is due to a bug in `FullGraphics`, the latter is used for avoiding a bug in `ImageResolution` which causes diminished `FrameTicks`. These bugs are not critical for this application: instead of `FullGraphics` one can use the `CustomTicks` package which "fixes" all these bugs.

```
S0 = Show[
   FullGraphics[
     Graphics[{}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
      PlotRange -> {{-10.1, 11}, {-45, 45}}, 
      AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]] /. 
    AbsoluteThickness[_] -> Thickness[Medium], 
   AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
   Epilog -> {Disk[#, Scaled[.0004 {1, GoldenRatio}]] & /@ data}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> Scaled[.02], FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}, 
   ImageSize -> {360, Round[360/GoldenRatio]}, 
   ImagePadding -> {{Scaled[.04], Scaled[.01]}, {Scaled[.04], 
      Scaled[.01]}}];
p = Graphics[Inset[S0, {0, 0}, Center, {1, 1}], 
  PlotRangePadding -> None, ImagePadding -> None, ImageMargins -> 0, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1/2, 1/2}, {-1/2, 1/2}}]

divisions = 4;
bins = Partition[FindDivisions[{-1/2, 1/2}, divisions], 2, 1];
plotRanges = Table[{x, y}, {y, Reverse@bins}, {x, bins}];
fileNames = 
  Table[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, 
     "temp part " <> ToString[i] <> ".mx"}], {i, 1, 
    Length[Flatten[plotRanges, 1]]}];

Do[Print@Export[fileNames[[i]], 
   ColorConvert[
    Rasterize[Show[p, PlotRange -> Flatten[plotRanges, 1][[i]]], 
     "Image", ImageResolution -> 400], "Grayscale"]], {i, 1, 
  Length[Flatten[plotRanges, 1]]}]

(*ImageTake drops last line of white pixels: it is a bugfix*)
Export["Graphics.eps", 
 ImageAssemble[
  Partition[
   Table[ImageTake[Import[file], {1, -2}], {file, fileNames}], 
   divisions]]];

FileByteCount["Graphics.eps"]

DeleteFile /@ fileNames;
```

> ```
> 1653237
> ```

We have generated a 8000x8000 image and exported it to EPS. Here is how it looks in Acrobat:

[image: screenshot 3]

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your pdf output. It creates a huge .svg file (about 7MB) and then when I import it into Inkscape I loose the Fonts and the special characters (like the OverDot in the y label). Also when I export it as .eps I choose 1000 dpi resolution but again the image is not the desired ...

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z I also loose the `OverDot` when exporting to `"SVG"` and the font becomes Arial. But the problem was not the font: it is easy to add axes labels in Inkscape (or even Acrobat Pro 11). I give a solution to control point's size.

Comment: Yes, indeed the fonts was not the problem. However, the exported .eps file form Inkscape (or GIPM) is about 20MB size! And then, you have to make extra modifications regarding the fonts. I want to believe that there must be another more direct for solving to my problem. Your solution requires an intermediate program. I refuse to believe that something so easy in `gnuplot`, requires too much effort in `Mathematica`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov That's a brilliant trick - never seen it before. For EPS, you can do: `StringReplace[
  ExportString[S0, "EPS"], {" " -> " ", 
   " 1 w" -> " 0.3 w"}] >> "test.eps"` to lower the line weight (where the first string is a tab, which gets translated to RawTab...)

Comment: @cormullion Thanks! This works perfect: `SetOptions[OpenWrite, PageWidth -> Infinity, FormatType -> OutputForm];
StringReplace[
  ExportString[S0, "EPS"], {"\t" -> " ", 
   " 1 w" -> " 0.3 w"}] >> "test.eps"`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Your revised method is working fine! Could you explain what exactly `{Disk[#, .01] & /@ data}` does? However, the exported eps file is about 30MB! The corresponding eps obtained from `gnuplot` is less than 1MB!

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Your .eps output is exactly the same (regarding the size of the dots) with the one I obtained using `gnuplot`. The only problem is the exported eps from `Mathematica` is about 30 times bigger in size! Why this is happening since visually the quality is the same? Is there a way to reduce its size?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I have a suspicion that `gnuplot` does not export "true" vector drawings, where one can access to every point as to separate object, but "bitmappes" them in high resolution -
therefore that output is not so "heavy". Can be done the same with `Mathematica`?

Comment: Perhaps some system dependacy? On linux export to EPS produces a real vector eps file with no preview.  The file size is essentilaly unchanged if you vary ImageSize.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z As I understand, PostScript is not just a vector format but also a *program* and there may be many ways to reduce filesize by some optimizations. May be `gnuplot` uses some optimization tecnique. The 30 times difference is not surprising me.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z See "EDIT 3" section for rasterized solution.

Comment: @george2079 See "EDIT 3" on how to add a preview. By default *Mathematica* does not include a preview into exported EPS file. The file size of purely vector drawing should not depend on the specified size of the drawing, nothing unexpected.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z See corresponding Documentation pages: ["Function (&)"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html), ["Map (/@)"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html), ["Disk"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Disk.html).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov For `ImageResolution->1000` the kernel shuts down, even though I have 4GB of memory. I know that my OS (Win XP 32bit) cannot access more than about 3GB of memory. So, `Mathematica` should at least use these 3GB. I reduced Resolution to 500 and the output is decent.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov By the way, I plan to upgrade my PC using Win XP 64bit with 16GB of RAM. In this 64bit OS how much RAM can `Mathematica 9` access to?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Mathematica starting at least from version 5 is shipped with 64bit versions of MathKernel and FrontEnd. AFAIK it should see all your memory, even 100 Gb of RAM on 64 bit systems.

Answer (score 4):

Poincaré sections like this are terrible when you include them in a multi-page `PDF` document (e.g. via $\LaTeX$) as vector graphics because they slow down then scrolling and paging for the reader, to the point where it becomes unbearable. Vector graphics is simply an inefficient and inappropriate way to represent graphics that mainly consist of giant point clouds. In particular for publication purposes, you should *always* convert such plots to bitmap!

It's not so much the storage that't the problem, it's the fact that the `PDF` interpreter has to decode the points every time you come to the page that displays your plot, and that takes a lot of pointless processing for lots of points (pun intended). Just export to `PNG` and forget about `EPS`.

Or (if you use an old $\LaTeX$ version) use the following trick from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18631/245) to create your `EPS` file with rasterized points:

```
rasterTrick[plot_] := 
Show[plot, 
 Prolog -> {Opacity[0], Texture[{{{0, 0, 0, 0}}}], 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
   Polygon[{{0, 0}, {.1, 0}, {.1, .1}}]}]

Export["t.eps", Style[S0 // rasterTrick, Magnification -> 2]]
```

Comment: I followed the `rasterTrick` you described but in the exported .eps file almost half of the plot (yes indeed it is a Poincare Surface of Section - PSS) is missing!

Comment: It works for me. Always has. What part of the plot is cut off? Or do you mean that certain points are missing from the plot?

Comment: See my EDIT. I provide the exact .eps output in which the entire right part of the PSS is missing.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z what you see is going to depend on the software you use for viewinng, which is why people are getting different results here.  Some viewers auto scale to fit the page, some don't.

Comment: @george2079 How can I rescale it in order to fit the page? I use GSview 5 to view .ps/eps files.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your `ImageSize` option? 550 seems very low...

[image: screen grab]

Comment: I can go up to about `ImageSize->600`. Beyond that I cannot export in .eps the entire plot. But again if I use larger `ImageSize` the size of the dots is still the same.

Comment: with this approach what you need to do is increase imagesize *and* add scaling code to the postscript output to scale it back down to fit the page.  This will effectivly shrink everything, points, lineweights, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems if you specify markers then the size is not cut off at some arbitrary threshold:

```
 ListPlot[data,PlotMarkers->{Graphics[Disk[]],.01}]
```

Note this *will* increase your file size quite a lot since mathematica draws the filled disk using 8 bezier curves, each one hard coded (48 floats (400+ bytes) for each marker)

The default marker is drawn as a zero-length line with round end caps. I guess somebody doesn't like the arc operators.

---

Yet another approach, this replaces your marker with arbitrary postscript code:
(no messing around with imagesize)

```
SetOptions[OpenWrite, PageWidth -> Infinity, FormatType -> OutputForm]
StringReplace[
      ExportString[ListPlot[data], "EPS"] , {"\t" -> " ", 
         " m 0 0 rL s\n" -> " mymarker\n", 
        "%%EndComments" -> 
        "%%EndComments\n/mymarker {dup 2 index exch moveto 1 0 360 arc fill} def\n"} ] >> test.ps
```

Note this is defining a procedure for the marker and so will not baloon your file size.
The `1` in `1 0 360 arc` is the marker radius, which can be as small as you like.