# Is it possible to draw really thin lines in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphics, system-limitations

I want to have in Mathematica the same result I have in Python: 
[image]

I have this nice effect simply by using very thin lines. But it seems in Mathematica thickness property has some limit and i just got this:

```
xy = RandomReal[1, {10000, 2}];
ListLinePlot[xy, PlotStyle -> Thickness@10^-5]
```

[image]

Playing with opacity doesn't help. I can't figure out how to reproduce this effect..

Comment: python has no built in plot. you ought to specify what module you are using

Comment: It's matplotlib

Comment: @funnypony Under which operating system have you taken the screenshot?

Comment: Nice pict. It can be used as wallpaper to simulate an erased blackboard.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Win7 (IPython notebook from last python xy).

Comment: Can you please include the full Python code, cannot reproduce with the snippet you posted.

Comment: @BioGeek actually this is full code in IPython. In contrast with ordibary python.exe it automatically imports many libraries like numpy and matplotlib. If you want to do it manually - you need numpy and matplotlib. Then just add these 2 lines in the beginning: `from numpy import random;
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show` and add this in the end: `show()`. It should work

Comment: One small thing: `Thickness@10^-5` doesn't do what you think it does. It evaluates to `1/Thickness[10]^5`, which isn't `Thickness[10^-5]` like you want.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Right, thanks for the remark on precedence, I'd have never realize that

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66177/is-it-possible-to-draw-really-thin-lines-in-mathematica#comment185018_66178) raises interesting question:

> I got everything simply faded and flat, while in the example - its all
>   bright and sharp

I think the problem is related to the fact that *Mathematica*'s graphical functions always work in linear colorspace. Starting from [Pickett's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66179/280) with better resampling method, in version 10.0.1 we obtain:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
xy = RandomReal[1, {10000, 2}];
img = ImageResize[
  Rasterize[
   ListLinePlot[xy, ImageSize -> 10000, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1],(*Opacity[.5],*)Blue]], "Image"], 
  300, Resampling -> {"Lanczos", 30}]
```

> [image: img]

This image is obtained in the linear RGB colorspace while our monitors work in the [sRGB colorspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB). The problem is discussed in some details in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15596/280) question of mine. We may apply a gamma correction as a quick-and-dirty way to fix this:

```
img2 = ImageApply[#^1.3 &, img]
```

> [image: img2]

Still far from ideal. Playing with `Resampling` and using more correct method of converting the linear RGB into sRGB can help to produce better colors.

---

### UPDATE: A detailed analysis

I have found that `Resampling` methods `"Constant"` and `"Linear"` better reproduce the Python's result. Increasing the `ImageSize` (i.e. decreasing the actual thickness of the lines) also helps (but the memory required for the rasterization grows as the square of `ImageSize`!):

```
$HistoryLength = 1;
xy = RandomReal[1, {10000, 2}];
img = ImageResize[
  Rasterize[
   Style[ListLinePlot[xy, ImageSize -> 15000, AspectRatio -> 224/336, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Blue], 
     Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0], Antialiasing -> False], 
   "Image"], 336, Resampling -> "Constant"]
```

> [image: img]

Rescaling color intensities to run from 0 to 1 significantly improves the appearance:

```
img = Image[Rescale[ImageData[img]]]
```

> [image: img]

Compare with the Python's result:

```
origImgCrop = 
 ImageTake[
  Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycM0u.png"], {97, 310}, {42, 367}]
```

> [image: Python's image]

The difference is still noticeable. One possible reason is insufficient `ImageSize` but I cannot check this directly because `ImageSize` larger than `15000` will kill my system with 8 Gb of physical memory. Let us crop the `img` too and compare the horizontal lightness distributions in the images:

```
imgCrop = ImageTake[img, {6, -6}, {6, -6}]
```

> [image: imgCrop]

```
imgCrop // ImageDimensions
origImgCrop // ImageDimensions
```

> ```
> {326, 214}
> {326, 214}
> ```

Mean horizontal lightness distributions for Python's (blue points) and *Mathematica*'s (orange points) outputs can be computed by taking the intensity values of the first RGB channel (the Red channel) because the first and the second channels contain identical values and actually describe the lightness:

```
origHorSum = 
  Total[#]/Length[#] &@
   ImageData[origImgCrop, Interleaving -> True][[;; , ;; , 1]];
horSum = Total[#]/Length[#] &@
   ImageData[imgCrop, Interleaving -> True][[;; , ;; , 1]];

ListPlot[{origHorSum, horSum}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

> [image: plot]

Let us see how this plot changes if we set `ImageSize` to 10000:

> [image: plot for ImageSize->10000]

The same for `ImageSize -> 8000`:

> [image: plot for ImageSize->8000]

From these comparisons I conclude that we cannot reproduce the Python's appearance just by increasing `ImageSize`.

And finally, let us look at the "natural" appearance of the image obtained with `ImageSize->15000` by converting it into the sRGB colorspace (the function `linear2srgb` is [implemented by Jari Paljakka](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/161zLDfpGBs/Rtl5AM4Uki4J) and can be found in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15992/280)):

```
ImageApply[linear2srgb, imgCrop]
```

> [image: sRGB image obtained with ImageSize->15000]

---

### UPDATE 2: simulating an erased blackboard

In the comments [Sigur](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/13074/sigur) expressed the idea that this type of plot simulates an erased blackboard and can be used as a background for slides. In PowerPoint 2003 (which I currently use) slides by default have size 25.4x19.05 cm  with `AspectRatio -> 1905/2540`. For obtaining a 1680 pixels wide background images the above code can be modified as follows:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
xy = RandomReal[1, {10000, 2}];
img = ImageResize[
  Rasterize[
   Style[ListLinePlot[xy, ImageSize -> 15000, 
     AspectRatio -> 1905/2540, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Black], 
     Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0], Antialiasing -> False], 
   "Image"], 1680, Resampling -> "Constant"];
img = Image[Rescale[ImageData[img]]]
Export["erased blackboard.png", img]
img2 = ImageApply[linear2srgb, img]
Export["erased blackboard (sRGB).png", img2]
```

Optimized PNG files can be downloaded here: "[erased blackboard.png](https://mega.co.nz/#!tJJnnZIL!nYncCqMprzjMoZg-dLLR3R6yYihID8hC1bIOJXQCUNw)", "[erased blackboard (sRGB).png](https://mega.co.nz/#!oAY3BTrD!oZsWJnu3mmBr0OPvyw042Hkc_1iyyufl2F_qtj6Hdv0)".

---

### UPDATE 3: more about the erased blackboard

It seems that inverting the colors and blurring produces an image that feels more like true erased blackboard. With blur we need not lossless PNG anymore and can use lossy JPG compression to reduce the file size. Here is a way to do everything in *Mathematica* (images are clickable!):

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
xy = RandomReal[1, {10000, 2}];
img = ImageResize[
   Rasterize[
    Style[ListLinePlot[xy, ImageSize -> 15000, 
      AspectRatio -> 1905/2540, 
      PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], White], 
      Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0, Background -> Black], 
     Antialiasing -> False], "Image"], 1680, Resampling -> "Constant"];
imgBlur = Blur[Image[Rescale[ImageData[img]]], 3]
Export["erased blackboard blurred.jpg", imgBlur]
```

> [image: erased blackboard blurred.jpg]

```
linear2srgb = 
 Compile[{{Clinear, _Real, 1}}, 
  With[{\[Alpha] = 0.055}, 
   Table[Piecewise[{{12.92*C, 
       C <= 0.0031308}, {(1 + \[Alpha])*C^(1/2.4) - \[Alpha], 
       C > 0.0031308}}], {C, Clinear}]], 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]; imgBlur2 = 
 ImageApply[linear2srgb, imgBlur]
Export["erased blackboard blurred (sRGB).jpg", imgBlur2]
```

> [image: erased blackboard blurred (sRGB).jpg]

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! I'd never have thought this way. This is really a nice tool for additional tweaking of graphics.

Comment: I updated the answer with an extended analysis of the situation.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, I got *No more memory available*. I have 4gb of memory. How to execute your code above?

Comment: @Sigur You need at least 8 Gb of physical memory for evaluating the code in my answer. Having only 4 Gb you need to use special technique (incremental rendering) for reducing memory requirements: see Section "EDIT 4" in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19006/280) answer.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, thanks. I tried with `1000` instead of `10000` and the program is still running. Let's see. With your code, the output would be an image with `15000` of resolution?! I'd like to produce an image with black/white colours to use as background on slides similar to a erased blackboard.

Comment: @Sigur With my code you get a 336x224 pixels raster images. In principle you can just take an image from my answer and use `ColorConvert` for obtaining a grayscale version of it. Use `Binarize` for obtaining a black&white version. But probably 336x224 pixels size is insufficient for your purposes.

Comment: @Sigur For your pleasure I have generated a 1500 pixels wide version and uploaded it [here](http://i.imgur.com/6V9YspX.jpg). The same image with "natural" colors after converting to sRGB colorspace is [here](http://i.imgur.com/hqqsbHs.jpg).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, thanks so much for the gifts. I got it. I was generating images with fewer points and saving. After some 10 images I would merge them using GIMP. Your approach was faster. Nice!

Comment: @Sigur I added the "UPDATE 2" section in my answer dedicated to your idea.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov after some processing your image looks even cooler: http://i.imgur.com/1p5sEDr.jpg

Comment: @funnypony Now it is true **black**board! BTW, I notice that your image is blurred probably due to lossy conversion to JPG automatically applied by imgur.com (or you have made it intentionally?). I am not sure whether blurred version is better or worse as a background for slides. What do you think?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov oh no imgur.com by no means touches uploading images. It's me who simply applied several filters in photoshop. I converted it in jpg only 'cause it reduced file size 4 times. I argee blurring is unnecessary

Comment: @funnypony What was the idea? I see also a little of warm yellow added. The difference is just noticeable though.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov well blurring, sepia and vignette are just most common and straightforward effects one can apply to get a new feeling of an image. generally no particular idea)

Comment: @funnypony I have no experience with Photoshop filters and I find your result useful. Upon reflection I am inclined to believe that the blurred version should be better as a background for slides, because clear text in the foreground will be better emphasized. I am not sure what *vignette* filter does but *sepia* probably added a little of yellow.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, thanks. I came here to write about the black colour but funnypony already did it. Nice! I guess that some blur or emboss could make the white lines look more like erased chalk. Like white clouds instead of white thin lines. Anyway, thanks and cong. for the good result.

Comment: My bad! I guess I misread. I was talking about the lightness plots.

Comment: @Öskå I added an explanation of the lightness plots.

Comment: Thanks! I guess some axes label or a legend would have done it :)

Answer (score 18):

On-screen, lines are always at least 1 pixel wide in Mathematica, regardless of the thickness setting.  Not sure what you tried with `Opacity`, as it seems to be possible to achieve the same effect:

```
PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Opacity[.05]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 10):

You tried to decrease the width of the lines to below the minimum width. In order to achieve the same effect you can increase the size of the image instead.

```
x = RandomReal[1, 10000];
y = RandomReal[1, 10000];
Show[ImageResize[Rasterize@ListLinePlot[{Thread@{x, y}}, ImageSize -> 10000], 300], ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image: example]

Comment: thx, but it has same problems as in previous answer (see comment)

Comment: @funnypony The default colors in Mathematica are not the same as the default colors in Python. For example if you set the color to `Blue` (`PlotStyle->Blue`) they look similar.

Comment: yes, now i think its right (sorry i mark previous answer due to priority). i made some tests - it seems python draws a little denser towards center.. http://i.imgur.com/BfW29S9.png

Comment: @funnypony Out of curiosity, why do you need to reproduce matplotlib's result with such fidelity?  If it's really important to have the exact same output, why not just use matplotlib?  Also, I guess matplotlib's output will depend on the precise rendering method and might easily change in the future.

Comment: @Szabolcs no, I don't need 'most idential plot ever') Initial idea was just to get something more or less similar to Python's plot - you can see my fail picture in the question, so solution with low opacity and pure blue color is completely fine.

Answer (score 0):

The OP has probably meant:

```
xy = RandomReal[1, {10000, 2}];
ListLinePlot[xy, PlotStyle -> Thickness@0.00001]
```

or

```
xy = RandomReal[1, {10000, 2}];
ListLinePlot[xy, PlotStyle -> Thickness@(10^-5)]
```

This seems to make a major difference, at least in Mathematica 13.2. Apparently "Thickness@10^-5" is not recognized properly.

Comment: Please include the plot to demonstarate that your approach works.

Comment: `Thickness@10^-5` evaluates to `1/Thickness[10]^5`. It's a syntax typo.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that! It did work on some previous mathematica, where I'd actually tested the script, but not anymore. @ operator has high precedence, so it evaluates first exactly as Sjoerd Smit written.