# Is it possible to specify a zero-thickness curve for a (filled) `ListPlot`?

Tags: plotting, graphics, system-limitations

With `Joined -> True`, `ListPlot`'s filling is solid by default.  But note that the filling and the line have different shades:

```
ListPlot[
  Table[{x, Sin[x Pi]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.025}]
  , Filling -> Axis
  , Joined -> True
  , ImageSize -> Small
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

AFAICT, one cannot get a curve with zero thickness:

```
ListPlot[
  Table[{x, Sin[x Pi]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.025}]
  , Filling -> Axis
  , Joined -> True
  , PlotStyle -> Thickness[0]
  , ImageSize -> Small
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is that *really* true?

---

PS: yes, I know that I can muck with the curve's color and/or opacity to simulate a zero-thickness curve in this case.  E.g.

```
ListPlot[
  Table[{x, Sin[x Pi]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.025}]
  , Filling -> Axis
  , Joined -> True
  , PlotStyle -> Opacity[0]
  , ImageSize -> Small
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But I just want to confirm that, indeed, *Mathematica* won't let you have a zero-thickness curve.

Comment: (you can also use `PlotStyle -> None`)

Comment: A zero thickness curve would be invisible -- Maybe it does draw one. :)

Comment: Related: "[Is it possible to draw really thin lines in Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66177/280)"

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov That's the one I was looking for but I only found [(9189)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9189/121); thanks for linking it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot draw a sub-pixel-width line, at least in *Mathematcia* 10 under Windows:

```
SeedRandom[4];
pts = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}];
Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[0], Line @ pts}]
Graphics[{Thickness[0.000001], Line @ pts}]
```

[image]

As noted in other questions like [How can the opacity of a dense data set be automatically chosen?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9189/121) the solution is to use an [`Opacity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Opacity.html) less than one, or `PlotStyle -> None`, even though this displeases you.

Comment: A zero-width line is not sillier than a zero-opacity line.  They both produce the same visual effect.  I think something is lost when the semantics of `Thickness[0]` are special-cased like this.  There's something to be said for uniformity of interface.  And I disagree with your answer's first sentence: one *can* draw a zero-pixel line, vacuously.

Comment: @kjo (1) I never said a zero-width line was silly.  Sub-pixel-width lines are possible in other software; it seems entirely plausible that they would be supported in *Mathematica*. (2) If however they both produce the same visual effect then using opacity is a working solution, or work-around, which is all I can offer. (3) I agree, `Thickness[0]` or perhaps even worse `AbsoluteThickness[0]` producing a 1-pixel-width line doesn't make sense. (4) I did write sub-pixel-width rather than zero-width for a reason.

Comment: Sorry, I did misread your post somewhat.

Answer (score 9):

It turns out you can, in fact, get a line with zero thickness. You can do this by passing a negative thickness as an argument to `Thickness`.

For instance, in your code example,

```
ListPlot[Table[{x, Sin[x Pi]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.025}], Filling -> Axis, 
 Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Thickness[-2], ImageSize -> Small]
```

Produces

[image]

This workaround does seen to have issues in other places, such as exporting the file, where it seems the magnitude of the thickness is used to produce the saved graphic.

Comment: This is new to me!  Thanks for posting. :-)

Comment: (+1) This works when `Export`ing to PDF, but not to EMF or PNG.