# Eliminating plot lines from a Filled (shaded) ListPlot

Tags: plotting

So, I just want to plot the area between two lines a color - the lines themselves should be invisible. It must be in ListPlot

```
l1 = Table[{n, n}, {n, 50}];
l2 = Table[{n, n - 10}, {n, 50}];
ListPlot[ {l1, l2}, Joined -> {True, True}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Lighter[LightBlue, 0.7]}}}]
```

That returns the area

[image]

But, I still need to remove the lines, lets try by making the thickness zero

```
ListPlot[ {l1, l2}, Joined -> {True, True}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0], Thickness[0]}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Lighter[LightBlue, 0.7]}}}]
```

Nope, that doesn't work.

[image]

Lets try a negative thickness.

```
 ListPlot[ {l1, l2}, Joined -> {True, True}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thickness[-2], Thickness[-2]}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Lighter[LightBlue, 0.7]}}}]
```

That works

[image]

Until you try to export it

```
graph = ListPlot[ {l1, l2}, Joined -> {True, True}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[-2], Thickness[-2]}, PlotRange -> All, 
   Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Lighter[LightBlue, 0.7]}}}];

Export["graphmew.jpeg", graph]
```

And our lines return.

[image]

Why do the lines return and how can I get rid of them.

Comment: Try with `Opacity`

Comment: A very similar question was posted recently: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139247/121  Incidentally I was *not* aware that `Thickness[-2]` would have the effect you show; I assumed it was invalid input.  Nevertheless that question itself contains what should be a working solution for you.  Please take a look and report if you have problems applying it.

Comment: By the way I suggest you post `Thickness[-2]` as an answer to that linked question; it is certainly relevant there and you deserve credit for posting it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
PlotStyle -> {None, None}
```

Comment: `PlotStyle -> None` is sufficient

Comment: @Bob Hanlon:  Yep.  Thanks.