# Why is `FindCycle` crashing for this graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, algorithm, crash

I'm working with a directed graph, previously mentioned in [Exporting a high-resolution GraphPlot of a very large graph (65,536 nodes)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113463/exporting-a-high-resolution-graphplot-of-a-very-large-graph-65-536-nodes). It can be generated with the following code:

```
  Hex[exp_] := FromDigits[exp, 16];
  LByte[exp_] := BitAnd[exp, Hex@"00ff"];
  HByte[exp_] := BitAnd[exp, Hex@"ff00"]~BitShiftRight~8;
  PRNG[v_] := Module[{L5, H5, v1, v2, carry},
    L5 = LByte@v*5;
    H5 = HByte@v*5;
    v1 = LByte@H5 + HByte@L5 + 1;
    carry = HByte@v1~BitGet~0;
    v2 = BitShiftLeft[LByte@v1, 8] + LByte@L5;
    Mod[v2 + Hex@"0011" + carry, Hex@"ffff" + 1]
    ];
  graph = # -> PRNG@# & /@ Range[0, Hex@"ffff"];
```

I know that there are 3 cycles in this graph. (See aforementioned link for a visualization.) However, running

```
FindCycle@graph
```

crashes the my kernel with no message in $Mathematica$:

[image]

This occurs even when I set limits on cycle length, *e.g.* `{100, 200}`, `{100, 4000}`, `{1000,2000}`.

Now, in my other question, I can understand why $Mathematica$ would have issues exporting a `GraphPlot` I rendered to have over 20 billion pixels. **But finding a cycle amongst 65,536 vertices should be no problem at all. Why is $Mathematica$ having trouble with this graph?** I'm running version 10.4.1.0.

---

To make sure I wasn't underestimating the complexity of cycle-finding, I put together my own function:

```
FindDirectedCycles[graph_] := Module[{limit, assoc, visited, count},
   limit = Length@graph;
   assoc = Association@graph;
   visited = <||>;
   count = 0;
   Scan[
    Module[{v, path, subvisited, subcount},
       v = #;
       path = {};
       subvisited = <||>;
       subcount = 0;
       While[count <= limit,
        If[KeyExistsQ[visited, v],
         Break[];
         ];
        If[KeyExistsQ[subvisited, v],
         path = Drop[path, subvisited[v] - 1];
         Print["Found a ", Length@path, "-cycle:"];
         Print[path];
         Break[];
         ];
        subvisited[v] = ++subcount;
        AppendTo[path, v];
        v = assoc@v;
        ++count;
        ];
       AppendTo[visited, subvisited];
       ]; &
    ,
    graph[[All, 1]]
    ];
   ];
```

**This code found the 3 cycles in less than two seconds.** Of course, my version makes the assumption that the graph is directed. But $Mathematica$'s documentation states that `FindCycle` should work for directed graphs. (Is it possibly because the graph consists of 3 unconnected subgraphs?)

Comment: Doesn't crash with v10.4.1 on OS X.  Anyway, if you see a crash, that's a bug.  If you can reproduce it, report to to support: http://www.wolfram.com/support/

Comment: I see, thanks. Can someone with Windows 7 try reproducing this issue please? Just copy and paste the code at the very top, then run `FindCycle@graph`. I'm running 64-bit.

Comment: I think you should report it to Wolfram even if not everyone can reproduce the crash.  Memory corruption bugs don't always result in a crash, but that does not mean that the bug is not there.

Comment: This crashes as well with 10.4.1 on Windows 8.1 for the directed graph.

Comment: Thanks @Xavier. Gotcha Szabolcs—I reported it (even before Xavier's input).

Comment: (1) It looks like there are three connected components and a much larger number of cycles. Finding components might be cheaper.

Comment: (2) Also if you want to work with the linear congruential equation directly, you can follow and perhaps coalesce chains fairly efficiently. Tht might give more or less equivalent information.

Comment: I've checked by zooming in at many seemingly intersecting points, and there are not more than 3 cycles. This has been verified by a previous researcher who independently found 3 cycles, and also Szabolcs and BobHanlon for whom `FindCycle` did not crash on OSX. Also, unfortunately this is not exactly an LCG because of the carry at 766 points. Appreciate your suggestions though!

Comment: Ah, I see I had an off-by-one problem in the (quite slow) code I ran. So three seems better(and, as you point out, has been verified). Now I get cycles of length 88, 810, and 2281, counting the edge from last to first.

Comment: This does not crash for me on 10.4.1 on Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly, technical support at $Mathematica$ was unable to reproduce the issue, though @Xavier and I were both able. They asked me to try [a clean start](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464), but the crash still occurred. I've sent my `SystemInformation[]`, and this issue is being tracked under `CASE:3588559`. The technician's last comments:

> I have filed a report with our developers which includes your SystemInformation so that they can look into this further.  I had tested with the FindCycle since I picked that up from the StackExchange thread.  Our developers may be able to do something in a future version of Mathematica if they are able to reproduce the problem.

If anyone else encounters this crash, please feel free to leave a comment with your OS and exact $Mathematica$ version; their developers have been forwarded a link to this thread.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(*  "10.4.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"  *)

Hex[exp_] := FromDigits[exp, 16];
LByte[exp_] := BitAnd[exp, Hex@"00ff"];
HByte[exp_] := BitAnd[exp, Hex@"ff00"]~BitShiftRight~8;
PRNG[v_] := Module[{L5, H5, v1, v2, carry}, L5 = LByte@v*5;
   H5 = HByte@v*5;
   v1 = LByte@H5 + HByte@L5 + 1;
   carry = HByte@v1~BitGet~0;
   v2 = BitShiftLeft[LByte@v1, 8] + LByte@L5;
   Mod[v2 + Hex@"0011" + carry, Hex@"ffff" + 1]];
graph = # -> PRNG@# & /@ Range[0, Hex@"ffff"];
```

Your `graph` is not a `Graph`. Use [Graph](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html)

```
GraphQ[graph]

(*  False  *)

gr = Graph[graph]
```

[image]

To find all cycles

```
Length[FindCycle[gr, Infinity, All]] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.513043, 3}  *)
```

Which confirms that there are three cycles.

**EDIT:** Supporting [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) comment below that "Since M10.3, most (all?) Graph-processing functions accept a rule list as an alternative graph specification."

```
And @@ (SameQ @@ (# /@ {gr, graph}) & /@
   {EdgeRules, EdgeList, VertexList,
    AdjacencyMatrix, IncidenceMatrix,
    KirchhoffMatrix, WeightedAdjacencyMatrix,
    FindCycle[#, Infinity, All] &})

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: Still crashes for me. May I ask what OS and Mathematica version you're using?

Comment: @Andrew M10.4.1 for OS X, it's at the top.  @Bob: Since M10.3, most (all?) `Graph`-processing functions accept a rule list as an alternative graph specification.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't there in the original post. Thanks.

Comment: @Szabolcs - thanks for pointing that out.