# How to plot DensityHistogram in Log scale

Tags: plotting, histograms, logarithmic-scale

My question is related to that question in this link [How: 2D scatterplots with quantitative density-dependent coloring](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85530/how-2d-scatterplots-with-quantitative-density-dependent-coloring)

So how to make the following Density Histogram plot in log scale

```
DensityHistogram[data, "Wand", "Count", ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
ChartLegends -> Automatic]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is not what you want please clarify your question:

```
data1 = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {2, 3}, 0.5], 100000];
data2 = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{3, 4}, {2, 2}, .1], 100000];
data = data1~Join~data2;

DensityHistogram[data, {"Log", "Wand"}, "Count",
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 ChartLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
DensityHistogram[data, "Wand", {"Log", "Count"},
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 ChartLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
DensityHistogram[data, {"Log", "Wand"}, {"Log", "Count"}, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
 ChartLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The plain form for comparison:

```
DensityHistogram[data, "Wand", "Count",
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 ChartLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! your solution is useful.

Comment: How could this be modified so that only the y-axis is log scale?