# Why does this simple program leak memory?

Tags: export, memory

I have a simple Mathematica program which writes some plots to image files for later conversion into a movie.  Unfortunately, the program leaks so much memory that it quickly exhausts all 12G of RAM on my machine.  The only way out is to quit the kernel(s).

I can't see why this program shouldn't use a bounded amount of memory.  I've read through [Debugging memory leaks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6177/debugging-memory-leaks) which unfortunately hasn't helped - the only "heavy" symbol is 'data', whose size is fixed.  I don't see what's growing!

Note that the same problem occurs regardless of whether the loop is Map or Do, Parallel- or not.  The problem also occurs in both Mathematica 8 and 9, both under Linux.

Help?

```
(* number of frames *)
n = 1000;
(* just some bogus data *)
makeData[_] := Table[{{x, y} = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {2}], {y, -x}}, {200}];
data = Array[makeData, n];
(* Export the frames *)
ParallelMap[
  Export[
    "movie-" <> IntegerString[#, 10, 4] <> ".png",
    ListVectorPlot[data[[#]]]] &,
  Range[1, n]];
```

**Edit**:
Some more information: after running this code (the non-parallel version), I checked the memory usage of the processes involved.  The percentages are out of 12GB, so both the frontend and the kernel are consuming quite a bit of memory, while PNG.exe is almost nonexistent.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
24575 gredner   20   0  4400  740  588 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 Mathematica        
24646 gredner   20   0 3029m 2.3g  22m S    0 20.5   1:43.02 Mathematica        
24655 gredner   20   0 3384m 1.6g  14m S    0 13.7   3:31.47 MathKernel         
24984 gredner   20   0  387m 7364 2464 S    0  0.1   0:20.92 PNG.exe
```

Comment: Have you tried using `ParallelDo` rather than `ParallelMap`? I know it shouldn't make a difference, but some of these things are more involved than they seem. Also try just plain `Do`. Maybe your system is launching like, infinity kernels all of which are running 100 computations, so you may need to specify things like `Method -> "EvaluationsPerKernel" -> 1`

Comment: I've now tried ParallelDo with the same outcome.

Comment: Regarding the number of kernels - it's bounded at 8 (which I have verified with 'top'), each of which consumes about the same amount of memory, all of which increase as the program runs.  Also, nothing changes if I use plain 'Map' with no parallel stuff.

Comment: How about `$HistoryLength`? It might be that it is remembering all the images. Try setting it to a much smaller value like 100 (the default is `Infinity`).

Comment: @bill s: Thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately changing $HistoryLength to a small value has no effect on the memory usage.

Comment: Have you tried removing the set of data used on every export? Something like `data[[#]]={}`?

Comment: @Spawn1701D: No effect :-\

Comment: What Mathematica version are you using? I know from my own experience doing this exact sort of thing (exporting images) that there is an inexplicable memory issue in my version 8 which didn't occur at all in my V9 trial from the same exact copy-pasted code.

Comment: Have you tried inserting `$HistoryLength=0` inside `ParallelMap` like `ParallelMap[$HistoryLength=0;Export...]`

Comment: @amr: I was using 8, but have just now upgraded to 9 - same behavior.

Comment: @Spawn1701D: I haven't, but the problem is the same if I use plain Map or Do, so that variable being different in different kernels can't be the problem.

Comment: Have you checked if the MathKernel itself leaks memory or the spawned PNG.exe processes?

Comment: It could also be the front end that leaks, check that process as well.

Comment: I've added information about process-specific memory usage to my question.  The punchline is that both the frontend and the kernel are eating a lot of memory, but PNG.exe almost none.

Answer (score 3):

## Extended comment

I ran this code several times, with different values for `n`, and using `Map` or `Do` as well as `ParallelMap`. Each time a plot was created and exported, *Mathematica's* memory in use increased by about 1.7MB. We can call this a 'leak', but it seems to be by design.

So, with `n` as 1000, and allowing for some memory for the front end and the kernel to start with, 1000 plots uses up some but not all the available memory. (Hence my original answer - your code runs fine as it stands.)

When `n` reached 4000, my computer started to run out of memory — paging continuously, or '[thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science))'.  Although it says 12GB total memory, the operating system needs some to work with as well.

I was unable to get to 10000 plots, for which my calculations suggest I'd need over 15GB of free memory devoted to `Mathematica`.

`ParallelMap` speeds up the process of generating the plots considerably, but it seems that each kernel uses free memory at the same rate as a single kernel, so the end result is that the computer starts to thrash sooner rather than later.

Anyway, my opinion is that there should be a way to make Mathematica forget about each plot once you've written it to disk.

Comment: Can you try increasing the number of frames (say increasing it by a factor of 10), re-running the experiment, and looking at memory usage again?

Comment: @GRedner might be able to some time, but my kernels are having a break for the weekend. (As am I...)

Answer (score 3):

**Another glorified comment**

The leak is not in `Export`. It is in `ListVectorPlot`.

Compare

```
tt = Table[{y, -x}, {x, -3, 3, 0.2}, {y, -3, 3, 0.2}];
before = MemoryInUse[]; ListVectorPlot[tt]; after = MemoryInUse[];
after - before
```

with

```
before = MemoryInUse[]; Identity[tt]; after = MemoryInUse[];
after - before
```

Comment: Just a (late) note for people hitting on this question: The problem seems to have been fixed in Mathematica 10.0.2.0.