# Is mathematica storing information it shouldn't store?

Tags: numerical-integration, memory

I'm seeking to find solutions to a numerical integration with a large set of parameter combinations (basically, I'm doing a brute parameter sampling). Yet, I believe the memory of the computer is storing unnecessary information, but I can't understand why: the memory stores near 16Gb of memory coming from Mathematica Kernel, while the output is only ~25mb. This sometimes makes the computer run out of memory and Kernel quitting. I am also afraid this may slow my computations.

I will abbreviate a lot the code because I just want to know if I'm doing something fundamentally wrong with my rationale, specially on **point 3 below**. Basically, I am numerically integrating some equations for many parameter values. The output of the integration is then used to compute values of the dependent variables at specific time points. These values are my output ~25 mb.

### **Note that I simplified my code a lot**, and also left some of it blank because it is unnecessary to explain what I am doing. What I'm doing is the following:

**1- Considering a very large table**

```
Table4 =
  Sort[
   Flatten[
    Table[
     {10^b, 10^g, 10^v, 10^k}, {b, -5, 5, 0.5}, {g, -7, 3, 
      0.5}, {v, -11, -1, 0.5}, {k, -8, 2, 0.5}
     ],
    3]
   ];
```

**2- I have a function `deqns4` that is simply a system of ODEs to be numerically integrated** and is called several times in **point 3** (This is a random system of equations, my real one has 13 dependent variables).

```
deqns4[b_, g_, v_, k_] :=
  {A'[t] == ki H[t] + k X[t] - b A[t],
   X'[t] == g A[t] - v X[t] - kc X[t],
   A[0] == 2,
   X[0] == 1
   };
```

**3- Then, the following function calls `deqns4` several times, to **numerically integrate the equations and output the values of the dependent variables** at some time points, for the given parameter values in `Table4`:

```
lsim4[{b_, g_, v_, k_}, ba_] :=  
Block[{ep, initconds, sssol0, tsim4, tsim3, tsimc50, tsimc100, c1,     c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7},
     (*This finds initial conditions*)   
sssol0 = Cases[
     NSolve[
      Rationalize[
       Evaluate[{
           ki H + k X - b A == 0,
           g A - v X - kc X == 0} /. ki -> 2 /. kc -> 0.1
        ],
       0
       ],
      {A, X}
      ],
     {Rule[_, _?NonNegative] ..}
     ] /. {A -> A0, X -> X0};

(*This and the following commands use the initial conditions above to numerically integrate the system of equations "deqns4"*)
tsim4 = Flatten[
    NDSolve[
     Rationalize[
      Evaluate[
       Join[
          {H[t] == 0.009 Exp[-0.1 t] + ba },
          deqns4[b, g, v, k]
          ] /. kc -> 0.1 /. sssol0],
      0
      ],
     {A, X, H},
     {t, 0, 9720}, MaxSteps -> 1*^12
     ],
    1
    ];

(*tsim3, tsimc50, and tsimc100 are also numerical integration of deqns4,    similarly to tsim4*)
tsim3 = Flatten[NDSolve[(*...left blank to simplify...*)], 1];
tsimc50 = Flatten[NDSolve[(*...left blank to simplify...*)], 1];
tsimc100 = Flatten[NDSolve[(*...left blank to simplify...*)], 1];

(*then I want the output to be a set of values computed from the \ numerical integration above*)   c1 = (A[324] + X[324]) 100 /. tsim4;
     c2 = (A[9720]) 100/(A[0]) /. tsim4;
     c3 = (X[3240]) 100 /. tsim4;
     c4 = (X[9720]) 100 /. tsim4;
     c5 = (A[3240] + X[3240]) 100 /. tsim3;
     c6 = (X[3240]) 100 /. tsimc100;
     c7 = (X[3240]) 100 /. tsimc50;
     {c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7}
     ];

lsimsols = ParallelMap[lsim4[#, 1.2] &, Table4];

(*output is a list with the form lsimsols={{0.1,0.99,100,0.52,76,100,100},{0.01,0.99,90,53,75,100},etc}*)
```

### My questions are the following:

1. Is `NDSolve`storing information each time it runs, though it is within a `Block` function?
2. The function `lsim4` is only outputing `c1` to `c7` for each element of `Table4`. This is what is being stored by `lsimsols`, and is the only information I am interested in. Yet, a lot more data is being stored by the kernel. Is there any way for me to avoid storage of so much information?
3. Even without specifying `MaxStepSize`, takes me ~4 hours to run all the values of parameters. Is there any more efficient way of doing this parameter sampling other than `ParallelMap`?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

- as suggested in the comments, I set `$HistoryLength=0` **which did not change all the memory allocated to Mathematica** - I still get about 16 Gbs of stored information.
- Also, `ParametricNDSolve` seems to produce faster results than `NDSolve`.

**Edit #2:**

- Someone suggested to use `Map` instead of `ParallelMap`, as this would possibly allow less memory usage. This didn't make any improvements.
- The only way I was able to attain a partial solution to the problem above is by splitting `Table4` in multiple parts and run `deqns4` for each part separately and then joining everything.

Comment: Have you tried setting `$HistoryLength` to something other than `Infinity` (the default)?

Comment: I have had that problem twice. The kernal stops when you run out of swap file space, so you might get it done by increasing the swap file. If this is something to be done often, you will need a better algorithm.

Comment: @Sosi, you could use `ParametricNDSolve`. As pointed out above try `$HistoryLength=0`

Comment: @bills - I've never heard of that. I'll look into it!

@FredKline - sorry to ask, but how do you do that?

@ruebenko - I'll check `ParametricNDSolve`. I think I've used it before.

Comment: Ok, I set `$HistoryLength=0` but Mathematica still steals all memory.

Using `ParametricNDSolve` made the computations faster though, but I then have to export the output, quit the kernel, import, and only then I can actually do something in mathematica

Comment: Does any of you think the problem may be related with what Oleksandr suggested in here (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/transferring-a-large-amount-of-data-in-parallel-calculations)? I am getting some errors from some evaluations and I am wondering if it also has something to do with this

Comment: I think I [agree](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24461/why-does-this-simple-program-leak-memory/24568#24568) that Mathematica stores things after it makes them - but I don't know of a solution...

Comment: Ah, I see. No workaround this then.
Thanks anyway @cormullion and everyone else!

Comment: Well there might be some ``System`Delete`Object`` function hiding down in the caves, who knows?! :)