# AndersonDarlingTest and DistributionFitTest Leaking Memory

Tags: bugs, memory, distributions

I believe `AndersonDarlingTest` and probably all other tests are keeping a copy of data somewhere and not freeing it:

```
Quit[]; (*Must be run in different cell*)


$HistoryLength = 0;
memdata = {{MemoryInUse[], MaxMemoryUsed[]}}~Join~Table[
     data = 
      RandomVariate[
       MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 1/2}, {1/2, 2}}], 1000000];
     dist = MultinormalDistribution[{ux, uy}, {{a, c}, {c, b}}];
     AndersonDarlingTest[data, 
      dist, {"FittedDistributionParameters", "PValue"}];
     Clear@data; Clear@dist;
     ClearSystemCache[];
     {MemoryInUse[], MaxMemoryUsed[]}
     , {10}]/1024.^2;

ListPlot[Transpose@memdata, Joined -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"MemoryInUse", "MaxMemoryUsed"}, Top], 
 AxesLabel -> {"Iteration", "Memory (MB)"}]
```

[image: example of memory leak]

**Questions:**

- **Am I missing something obvious or is this a bug?** Just want to make sure before I report it...
- **Is there a work around?** I've been spelunking with the excellent [spelunking package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/what-is-the-most-convenient-way-to-read-definitions-of-in-memory-symbols-when-we), but so far no luck...

[Heavy symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6179/745) gives some candidates, but clearing the symbols in the loop gives me various errors.

```
heavySymbols["Statistics`*`"]

{"Statistics`GoodnessOfFitTestingDump`iHypothesisTestFunction", 
 "Statistics`StableEstimationDump`iLogPDF17", 
 "Statistics`StableEstimationDump`iPDF05b1"}
```

Using MMA 9.0.1 on Win7 64 bit.

Comment: I can confirm that this happens to me too (but then, I run MMA on a similar system).

Comment: Same result on OS X.

Comment: Not so darling ...

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Do you have MMA 10 or 11? Is this fixed in the newer versions?

Answer (score 3):

`iHypothesisTestFunction` seems to grow each iteration. But I have no idea, how to fix it. If I clear the whole object the tests stop working.

[image: Example of memory abuse]

```
$HistoryLength = 0;

Clear[$globalProperties];
$globalProperties = {OwnValues, DownValues, SubValues, UpValues, 
   NValues, FormatValues, Options, DefaultValues, Attributes, 
   Messages};

ClearAll[getDefinitions];
SetAttributes[getDefinitions, HoldAllComplete];
getDefinitions[s_Symbol] := 
  Flatten@Through[
    Map[Function[prop, 
       Function[sym, prop[sym], HoldAll]], $globalProperties][
     Unevaluated[s]]];

ClearAll[symbolMemoryUsage];
symbolMemoryUsage[sname_String] := 
  ToExpression[sname, InputForm, 
   Function[s, ByteCount[getDefinitions[s]], HoldAllComplete]];

GetMem[] := {MemoryInUse[], MaxMemoryUsed[], 
   symbolMemoryUsage[
    "Statistics`GoodnessOfFitTestingDump`iHypothesisTestFunction"]};
memdata = {GetMem[]}~Join~
    Table[data = 
      RandomVariate[
       MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 1/2}, {1/2, 2}}], 1000000];
     AndersonDarlingTest[data];
     Clear@data; Clear@dist;
     ClearSystemCache[];
     GetMem[], {10}]/1024.^2;

ListPlot[Transpose@memdata, Joined -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[{"MemoryInUse", "MaxMemoryUsed", "iHypothesisTestFunction"}, 
   Top], AxesLabel -> {"Iteration", "Memory (MB)"}]
```

Aha, it seems `iHypothesisTestFunction` is doing some caching, and I have to selectively remove the downvalues...

Here is the fix. Don't have time to describe in detail how it works. (basically I'm just resetting the  down values -- any suggestions welcome).

```
ClearAll@CleariHypothesisTestFunctionMemory;
CleariHypothesisTestFunctionMemory[] :=
  DownValues@
    Statistics`GoodnessOfFitTestingDump`iHypothesisTestFunction = 
   Uncompress@
    "1:eJztWktv4zYQtrOvPjZFu4cCfVwK9I1edlGgi/\
bkxnESYJ3Ekbd76SG0RNlEaFElqWT978sRrZclOxyt7UWBXgiTGc4M5/\
HNkMo3E3EVPux0OgqGV0zp8ABmH5vhKuG0TzlZ0CDsZounggeXRGsqI0v5oRmORBQwzcRy\
6Q8zeJpow4356vpEiCCiSl2EA6bH1CxG034yj6/Z6SIWekYVU7A8SCK/\
YJLp4z0zP8xGTYO+\
mUo2SYAoldtLtJgbOb7d8sQMS93UD446zHQQPoDNIKaqT59oUmf8syPjI8I5lWEH9j8yw5\
+cRDf3TFNhj80wJNqfjez8q6rAV2wiiVxcn477fxGeUMxJPTDqeBFT7ylsIvOY07E4Tzi3\
osAQHtXvy4sopx0UphP+TXhYlqZ+dGQUYIhjIpX6yZE4TFm7UgPxC/\
WdIzVxppw4mzQg2pk2pnP1vSPtXexMSqbOpDF1J3Xnqm7DxxkUHIl5LJIoOH4bS0ObB/\
QyRVARZgFmm3kMDE8uBt4HkM8AVTlwZ/qhIs9u/Qgwn8ac+LTHOe6ElWQvZlBCUkD7+/\
fBy+e/uUf4OhYv3UO/\
ag9EHuzOXQBXUFWeWxGg4FlY6NmLlrAGw4W0RffXZj2Mx31JNR0mXLNbIhnRtIysI5z/\
UlEvNot6HW1LEBz2XOhavetmTj+lJMCB+KdL05ZVax8B6UbXFGIx8Ze1+\
6mVdSmpzwAzUPALyXwWhSxielGZ7PMcePbbTBRoB3Lj1ZME+\
rDXkSJzOmqHxlDCbZT90qz1CdXlCLok0ggzfZ/CRXmnAoePXIsKogDvDqS+\
AB9k5z42NNCbiWhI9UyU8Mn4ZFMuo87yMMudHoce22y6NaTVDr9q0m59Bh1g2kZ79J+\
ERj7Ny4f9e95mF+\
sH9zkGAm5oFsiUFvei5cK5sRDyNpAWgJDpEFldu5ltr6hOzB3kMAWHABw0Z8ZctJ4qyxKS\
d8keJA2qw2u4YLVitOK5Vl1K2k3b5mylmctC3sQ7M5BETQ1dxqx79AP44jr1qm269QPmnQ\
vUpTdC3pj9BbDtFjeRQZnqOpYJDZ+\
44hSioW7oLJvWvE8sSwl77flRMbbBBU2sG2K7DQbnkNCn3CTjEVFIte9TtPGBAOuFu7jRC\
w8y5S9iwHcr8MsOXNOjYE0RxODH+sjPk6PBDbvrJlrZjkx3bqe07vl+Iom/\
OBGEt1M0pjtX9FlDYyBkS3V3b9fDsvfrhv2vlh4E9ja8626sS2hEybmtxjAmv6qcal7DhF\
SVVXO8Yt6Y2hbScpO8oRvDvSVCdf52QBjPnuOzzjudrKhaurvneXSeG2PU+OCDi0Nc/\
rRPvfK5UwsXz9UurQpOzU45Ywppte4a7khnUXpX4cbW5oeJgEVvomik38Wv76D6nj3acAd\
Bfjj6/ytRy69E3UzYkJmAj6beoQWCXhxz5pMJf8+u+LrRFaUqvkWnHOzZKbVHBvu4A+\
2Bd8e0P9vnN7syLKXO/dwMjTYf7ekTRA0oVx93MRLWpHQNeNZBERjuDdOzpsvh/\
h4O92T5/IloPJOUBCutEOqYuYGGJLZ8QVI12SGtjt9q0+/pbTm2eKUbMJn5CSRfCmX/\
uWCPlgTLeVxols7wUbIZnlMo+SyDEsjlHE62Cu7dbYD7emXLrcu/n5/PiQ==";
```

[image]