# Reading binary strings from file as strings

Tags: import, string-manipulation

I have a file that contains binary strings like

```
01011
00101
01011
```

I want to import the file to Mathematica as a list of strings, but

```
Import["test.dat", "Table"]
```

gave me

```
{{1011}, {101}, {1011}},
```

which is a list of numbers rather than strings.

What should I do to make sure that the binary strings are read as strings rather than numbers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `ReadList`:

```
ReadList["test.dat", String]
(* {"01011", "00101", "01011"}  *)
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to learn how to use the help file (Do press `F1` as often as possible, although to be fair the option is a bit hidden). You are looking for `"Numeric"->False` option. It can be found by pressing `F1` when the text cursor is over `Import`, click listing of formats, click Table and then option:

```
str = "01011\n00101\n01011"
ImportString[str, "Table"]
ImportString[str, "Table", "Numeric" -> False]

(*=> {{1011}, {101}, {1011}} *)    
(*=> {{"01011"}, {"00101"}, {"01011"}} *)
```

Comment: I did notice `ImportString` while I was searching the help files. However, `ImportString` reads from a string. Did you suggest that I have to copy and paste the file contents rather than reading from a file by giving the filename?

Comment: @wdg No, not at all. `Import` and `ImportString` take the same options. I used `ImportString` because it's easier to create a self contained example.

Comment: 5 upvotes for this simple answer, that took me las than 5 min to write as a break? Well thank you. But on this answer (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40687/745) I spent more than 3 hours and it only got 2 upvotes. Hmm, I still don't fully understand how mma.se works:)

Comment: @Ajasja It's _because_ it's simple.  Easy to understand the problem and easy to understand the answer.  The other question/answer is big and intimidating.

Answer (score 4):

```
str = "01011\n00101\n01011";
ImportString[str, "Lines"]
```

> {"01011", "00101", "01011"}