# Write memory usage to file in script

Tags: memory, scripting, save

Is there a way to write the MemoryInUse into a file once a minute?

In this [Debugging memory leaks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6177/debugging-memory-leaks) question there is a neat dynamic diagram showing the MemoryInUse over time. My problem is that I run my mathematica script without the front-end (math -script mystuff.m) and it seems that Dynamic does not work.

Comment: Maybe PutAppend is the function you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(* make the task, fires once a minute *)
task = CreateScheduledTask[PutAppend[MemoryInUse[], "myMemory.log"], 60];

(* start the task *)
StartScheduledTask[task]

(* ... do your thingys ... *)

(* stop (or remove) the task *)
StopScheduledTask[task]

RemoveScheduledTask[task]
```