# Module in numerical model for NonlinearModelFit is slow and leaks memory

Tags: fitting, scoping, memory, performance-tuning

I am trying to make a `NonlinearModelFit` where the model is the result of a numerical calculation. My code works, but it is very slow and also seems to have a memory leak.  I'd appreciate advice about how to improve the code, make it faster, and stop leaking.

A simplified version of my model is:

```
$HistoryLength=0;
model[gnIN_?NumberQ, gpIN_?NumberQ] :=
   Module[{rep, eqs, sol, t},
    rep = {gn -> gnIN, gp -> gpIN, n0 -> 10, p0 -> 0.01};
    eqs = {
     n'[t] == -gn (n0 + n[t]) f[t],
     p'[t] == -gp ((p0 + p[t])) (1 - f[t]),
     n[t] == p[t] +f[t],
     n[0] == 10, p[0] == 10, f[0] == 0};
    sol = NDSolve[eqs /. rep, {n, p, f}, {t, 0, 10}];
    First[(n[#] + p[#])/(n[0] + p[0]) /. sol] &]
```

[**Edit**: maximum time in `NDSolve` changed from 50 to 10. See comment below.] There are three coupled equations (one of them not a differential equation, so it could be removed easily). The output that I want for my model, however, is not `n`, `p`, or `f`, but rather `(n+p)/(n[0]+p[0])`. I have used a pure function to pass this out of the model, but I don't know if there's a better way.

We can make some fake data by

```
tmp = model[1,.1];
data = Table[{i, tmp[i]}, {i, 0, 50}];
```

I then call

```
MemoryInUse[]/10^6.
nlm=NonlinearModelFit[data, {model[gn,gp][t], gn>=0 && gp>=0},{gn,gp},t];
MemoryInUse[]/10^6.
```

This runs successfully, giving best fit parameters `{gn -> 1.04935, gp -> 0.0998232}`, but it takes several minutes -- 376 seconds [**Edit**: revised to 68 seconds], from `AbsoluteTiming` on my 3.2GHz i5 iMac running MMA 9.  (In this case, I could clearly give it excellent initial guesses, but that's a bit harder in my real problem. As an aside, giving it initial guesses of `{2,0.2}` causes it to take 450 seconds and return `{1.48,0.098}` as best fits, badly missing on `gn`.)

On this time that I'm running, the `MemoryInUse` commands return `92.9` and `101.1`. Running it again will cause steady increase in memory usage, which is why I believe there is a memory leak.

Running `Names["*$*"]` returns a list with many variables like n$10849.

```
Names["n*$*"]//Length
Names["p*$*"]//Length
```

returns `289` and `336`. I assume that all these `n` and `p` variables are being kept for some reason related to the return of the `Module`.  But if I run the `NonlinearModelFit` again, the total memory continues to rise, but the number of `n$*` and `p$*` variables does not continue to increase -- it seems to stay very close to 300, indicating that some garbage collection is occurring. Also, the total memory used by those `n$*` and `p$*` variables, using `symbolMemoryUsage` from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6179/7240), does not explain the increase in memory usage of the kernel. That is,

```
Total[symbolMemoryUsage /@ Names["*n$*"]]
Total[symbolMemoryUsage /@ Names["*p$*"]]
```

returns `13872` and `16176`, which is much less than the 8 MB increase in memory use on running the `NonlinearModelFit`. In my actual case, the increased memory use can reach over 5 GB (and grind my computer to a halt) before `NonlinearModelFit` finishes. In this simple case, the leak is smaller, but it is still there.  Running

```
MemoryInUse[]/10^6.
AbsoluteTiming[Do[model[1, .1], {i, 1, 1000}];]
MemoryInUse[]/10^6.
```

returns `104.161`, `4.34`, and `104.261`. So the memory increase is about 100 KB with each 1000 evaluations of `model`. When I add a simple counter into `model` to count the number of times it is evaluated during the `NonlinearModelFit`, the answer is about 85000, indicating that the 8 MB increase in memory use is mostly due to a leak from `model`. Similarly, the time to evaluate `model` 85k times should be about 370 seconds, which is close to the total evaluation time. The slowness of my code and the memory leak are all in my `model`.

I understand that there's a limit to how fast a model with `NDSolve` could possibly be, but I suspect it can be better than this. Previous discussions of `Block` vs. `Module` have left me concerned that `Block` will do things I don't understand, but I haven't tried it. Any advice for coding practice (in particular, better ways to return the function from `model` so it's in the correct format to put into  `NonlinearModelFit`), speed, or memory will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: In case people have been dissuaded from working on this problem by the running time of my example code, I have changed the maximum time of `NDSolve` in `model` from 50 to 10, which makes the `NonlinearModelFit` run in 68 seconds, rather than 376.  The memory leak is still there and of the same magnitude as in the original question. Any comments or advice welcome!

Comment: When I evaluate your example sequence, `model[1, .1]` complains with `NDSolve::ndinnt : Initial condition f0 is not a number or a rectangular array of numbers.` Are you using a specific definition for `f0` that you could edit into the question?

Comment: @billisphere Sorry about that! It's fixed now. I simplified the example when posting but didn't catch all my changes.