# Creating a bound method (partial function application)

Tags: functions, function-construction, functional-style

I want to bind arguments to methods (e.g. for use in OOP creating a bound method--what Java just calls a method). I realized this is basically just a [partial function application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). Now I want to make this in Mathematica.

My hope is to to make a `PartialFunction` object that formats nicely and uses `HoldAllComplete` when passing arguments through so as to really do nothing to them.

Of course, I can just do this:

```
partialFunction[func_, params__] :=
 Function[Null, func[params, ##], HoldAllComplete]
```

But this is just ugly to look at and gives me no hint as to what the `Options` are. Cleaner would be to do something like this:

```
partialFunction[func_Symbol, params__] :=

  Module[{func, cached = func},
   Options[func] = Options[cached];
   func[args___] :=
    cached[params, args];
   Format[func] =
    RawBoxes@
     BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[
      "partialFunction",
      func,
      None,
      {
       cached,
       BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Args: ",  Length@{params}}, 
        StandardForm]
       },
      {},
      StandardForm
      ];
   func~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete;
   func
   ];
partialFunction[func_, params__] :=

 Function[Null, func[params, ##], HoldAllComplete]
```

Which looks fine, preserves options, and is *almost* perfect except for that pesky detail of creating terrible memory leaks.

Consider the following:

```
m1 = Module[{m1 = MemoryInUse[]},
   partialFunction[Print, RandomReal[{}, {1000, 1000}]];
   m1
   ];
MemoryInUse[] - m1

8006848
```

Because `Print` is on the RHS of my `partialFunction` function that large matrix I created won't go out-of-scope until `Print` does. [This is discussed here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6179/38205). That seems to nix this otherwise really clean approach.

So how can we get partial function application that's nicer than just using `Function`?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind doing some radical surgery on [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function), you could do the following:

```
PartialFunction[s_, p__] := Function[Null, ipf[s, p, ##], HoldAllComplete]

Unprotect[Function];
MakeBoxes[Function[Null, ipf[s_, p__, ##], HoldAllComplete], StandardForm] ^:= 
BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[
    "PartialFunction",
    s,
    None,
    {s, BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Args: ", Length@Hold[p]}, StandardForm]},
    {},
    StandardForm
];
HoldPattern[Options[Function[Null, ipf[s_, __], HoldAllComplete]]] ^:= Options[s]
Protect[Function];

SetAttributes[ipf, HoldAllComplete]
ipf[sym_, params_, args__] := sym[params, args]
```

*(it would be better to make this a package so that `ipf` could be a private symbol)* For example:

```
pf = PartialFunction[Integrate, x^2]
```

[image]

and:

```
pf[{x,0,1}]
pf[{x,0,10}]
```

> 1/3
>
> 1000/3

Also, [`Options`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Options) works as desired:

```
Options[pf]
```

> {Assumptions :> $Assumptions, GenerateConditions -> Automatic, 
>    PrincipalValue -> False}

If the parameter is large, than the `PartialFunction` will be large, but there is no memory leak:

```
MemoryInUse[]
Module[{pf = PartialFunction[Print, RandomReal[1, {1000, 1000}]]},
    MemoryInUse[]
]
MemoryInUse[]
```

> 319084696
>
> 327086744
>
> 319086640

Comment: This is pretty good... I'm a bit concerned about fragility given the overloads and things, but overall it's a nice approach.