# Memory leak while using ParallelTable

Tags: function-construction, list-manipulation, parallelization, memory

I am populating a table using ParallelTable. The entries of this table are given by a function written as a module, which depends on several modules itself. Here's a rough skeleton of the code:

`func1[vars1_]:=Module[{locals1}, stuff happens; Return[answer1]`

`func2[vars2_]:=Module[{locals2}, other stuff happens including: func1[vars2]; Return[answer2]`

`datarun = ParallelTable[func2[vars2],{i,1,n},{j,1,m}]`

For small values of `n` and `m`, everything runs fine. However, for larger values, the memory usage on my machine slowly creeps up, until by the end it's using about 98% of the memory. This also has the effect of *vastly* slowing down the computation, which is the reason I'm so annoyed--if I evaluate the function `func2[vars2]` for one set of `vars2`, it takes a couple seconds, whereas in the loop, once the memory has been eaten up, it takes a few minutes.

Things I've tried: I put `ClearSystemCache[]` and `$HistoryLength=0` into each of my modules (after reading about similar problems [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6177/debugging-memory-leaks)). I also included the statement `ClearAll["Global'*"]` in my main function. These things helped a fair bit (the problem used to be much worse, I won't go into it), but it still seems that I have a memory leak somewhere. That all being said, my questions are:

1. Is there something about the way I've nested modules that makes such a thing ripe for a memory leak?
2. Being new to all this, how would I go about identifying where a memory leak was occuring?
3. Is there anything I can just add to my  code that ensures it won't keep around anything unnecessary that might cause a leak? (I thought that's what `ClearAll["Global'*"]` would do)

Also, in case it matters, my ParallelTable is using 12 cores, and the amount of memory that I have is 16 GB.

Comment: You keep saying it’s a memory leak. Are you sure? Or is it not just possible that you are generating a larger and larger result as you increase the max values of your iterators, which occupies more memory? It’s hard to be more precise with no details on what your code is doing and returning. Finally, in your notebook are you using the correct backtick ``ClearAll["Global`*"]``? You have an apostrophe here instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No, I'm not sure. But I don't think it can be that I'm just generating a larger and larger result, since when I run the functions one by one for large values of the iterators, it works fine.
Oh my gosh, no I had an apostrophe, so it was doing nothing. But putting it in correctly made me realize that I actually should not do that, since it clears all the functions and global variables and everything haha.... if only there were something like ```ClearAll["Global`*", except for this list of things that I want to keep]```. Is there such a thing?

Comment: You could use ``ClearAll[ Complement[Names["Global`*"], {symbols, to, keep}] ]``. However, I doubt that this is your problem or solution. What kind of objects, of what size, is your function returning (see `ByteCount` to measure size)? Does the same thing happen if you use `Table` instead of `ParallelTable`?

Comment: The size of the table in the end is roughly 160 KB, so I don't think that should be a problem. The function returns a 2 by n array, where n is some small number (like 10). Also, I'm checking now and it *does* seem to have the same issue using Table instead of ParallelTable.

Comment: Actually I take that back---with Table everything looks fine.

Comment: Also, that syntax you suggested for ClearAll won't work, I think--the syntax for ClearAll is ```ClearAll[a,b,c]```, not ```ClearAll[{a,b,c}]```

Comment: You're right about the syntax; I should have written ``ClearAll @@ Complement[Names["Global`*"], {symbols, to, keep}]``; that's what I get for posting from mobile without testing :-)